# Fazendo pesquisa de meus tópicos no StackOverflow

Tags: suporte

Como faço pra consultar todos os tópicos que eu criei no meu usuário do StackOverflow?

Comment: Basta informar na [caixa de busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) `user:me is:question` para retornar apenas suas perguntas. `user:me is:answer` retornará apenas suas respostas e `user:me` retornará suas perguntas e respostas.

Answer (score 9):

Como aqui não é um fórum você não criou um tópico, criou uma pergunta em um site de perguntas e respostas.

O que você quer está no seu perfil, especificamente em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/46920/dark777?tab=questions.

Lá tem a maioria das informações que possa desejar sobre o site. Você só precisa usar a busca quando quer algo mais específico, mais filtrado. A busca passada pelo Valdeir oferecerá de uma forma, geralmente, menos interessante que a aba que perguntas do seu perfil.

Se nada disto ajudar pode fazer um [busca avançada na base de dados do site](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/queries), tem tudo o que não viola privacidade lá, só precisa entender a estrutura e saber SQL para pegar o que deseja. Claro que a informação ali está sempre um pouco defasada.